# Fetching Records withing given range of timestamp from cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra, and I want to fetch the records which are in-between the given range of timestamps. What could be the query for this? I'm using the thrift client.

I tried this piece of code.

```
String columnFamily = "UserColumnFamily";
String keyspace="Enterprise";
final String UTF8 = "UTF8";
String keyUserid="1";
TTransport tr = new TSocket("10.10.10.104", 9160);
TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr);
Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate();
    SliceRange sliceRange = new SliceRange();
String startkey="1293443184521000";
String finishkey ="1293445102333000";        
sliceRange.setStart(new byte[0]);
        sliceRange.setFinish(new byte[0]);
predicate.setSlice_range(sliceRange);
        ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent(columnFamily);
       try {
    tr.open();
    List<KeySlice> results=client.get_range_slice(keyspace,parent,predicate,startkey,finishkey,100, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
      for (KeySlice result : results) {
           Column column = (Column) result.columns;
           System.out.println(new String(column.name,UTF8) + " ->> "
          + new String(column.value,UTF8));
       }
      tr.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it throws this error:

```
InvalidRequestException(why:start key's md5 sorts after end key's md5.
This is not allowed; you probably should not specify end key at all, under RandomPartitioner
```

And if I put the `finishkey` to `null` then it says:

```
Required field 'finish_key' was not present! 
  Struct: get_range_slice_args(keyspace:NiidleEnterprise, 
  column_parent:ColumnParent(column_family:UserColumnFamily), 
  predicate:SlicePredicate(slice_range:SliceRange(start:, finish:, reversed:false, count:100)), 
  start_key:1293443184521000, finish_key:null, row_count:100, consistency_level:ONE)"
```

I don't understand what value to set as `startkey` and `finishkey`.
In above code:

```
String startkey="1293443184521000";
String finishkey ="1293445102333000";
```

These are the timestamp values. Please suggest what should I take for start and finish keys?

Comment: What client are you using?  That information would make this a much more useful question.

Answer (score 5):

Please use [Hector, a java client library for Cassandra](https://github.com/rantav/hector) or one of the other clients available here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions. Using raw Thrift is slow, hard, and gotcha ridden way to go.

But, in general, you can't get a meaningful range of rows when using RandomPartitioner because rows are ordered by the MD5 hash of their keys.  Instead, you need to create your timeline within a row (or multiple rows) by using timestamps or TimeUUIDs for column names.  This will cause your columns to be chronologically sorted.  You can then either store your data as the column values, or you can store keys for the actual data rows as the column values.

Answer (score 2):

[Cassandra api](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API)

hint: [get_range_slices](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#get_range_slices)

Comment: Or even just get_slice() when it's a single row.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamps are there for conflict resolution for a given column. They are not there for searches. If you want to search by timestamp, you should put the timestamps into your data model (in keys, column names, or column values).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timestamp as column name to leverage column name sorting done automatically by Cassandra. The next questions that comes up is row size related. You may not be able to store all your time series data in one row. Your data may need to be broken up along several rows.

Depending on the amount of data being generated, you may choose different options. You may decide to store each day's data in a separate  row and the data with a row sorted by column name  as I mentioned. In this  case if the time range in your query spans day boundary, you will have to make multiple queries one for each row (i.e. day in your time span range). Essentially, the original  range query will translate to multiple range queries.